# Java Threads and Null Pointer Error

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I'm writing a bit of code for an imaginary AirLock system in a spaceship, and I use this method to randomly generate one of two random doors to be opened :

```
while (true){

        int doorNum = (int)((Math.random() * 10) % doors.length);


        doors[doorNum].requestToOpen();

        try{
            Thread.sleep(800);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

It picks out one possible door from an array of two and in the runnable AirLockDoor class I try and acknowledge the request and then log it down:

```
public void  requestToOpen() {

    System.out.println(doorName +  " requests to be opened");

    if(doorName.equals("Door 1")){
        Door1Status = true;
    }
    else if (doorName.equals("Door 2")){
        Door2Status = true;
    }


}
```

And within here, the doorName variable works fine, it will print out Door 1/Door 2  requests to be opened. But then when I try and log the request it gets weird. I've tried storing it as a String and and as a boolean, by setting the variable to be equal to doorName. And if I debug it, it does work and the new value gets set. But as soon as I want to use the value in my run() method of the runnable then the value goes null and the program throws a null exception error, and I have no idea what is going wrong. So any ideas here would be very appreciated

This is my run method, it totally ignores the if and if else and goes straight for the else:

```
public  synchronized   void run() { 
    while (true){
        if(lockOperator.isLockState()){
            System.out.println("Request denied, the lock is engaged");
        }
        else{
            if(Door1Status){
                System.out.println("Door 1 will open");
            }
            else if(Door2Status){
                System.out.println("Door 2 will open");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Else");
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line does the exception occur?

Comment: In the run method, I've added it to the main post

Comment: This would mean that either lockOperator or one of Door1Status and Door2Status has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few flaws here on an architectural level that may be contributing to the error, it's not obvious what's actually causing it without you posting the stack trace and showing what line the stack trace refers to though.

Use a `ScheduledExecutorService` rather than a thread with sleep.

Use an enum for door status or call the status either open or closed to it is clear what it means.

The door should know what door it is, no need to do a comparison on the door name.

The door object should contain its status.

i.e.

```
 public class Door {
     boolean open;
     String name;

     void setOpen(boolean open) {
         if (this.open == open) {
            return;
         }
         this.open=open;
         if (open) {
             System.out.println(doorName + " opens");
         } else {
             System.out.println(name + " closes");
         }
     }
 }
```